# Clarification on super script notation

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I'm following an algorithm for computing sparse singular vectors for an SVD decomposition. a part of the algorithm states:

1. set initial values $u^{0}$ and $v^{0}$ and set $i=0$
2. update $u$:

   $u^{i+1}  \leftarrow Kv^{i}$

   $u^{i+1} \leftarrow {u^{i+1} \over \Vert u^{i+1} \Vert}$

   $u_{j}^{i+1} \leftarrow (\vert u_{j}^{i+1} \vert - {1 \over 2} \lambda) $....

Where $u$ and $v$ are left and right SVD matrices of singular vectors, and $K$ is a matrix. I'm wondering what the super and subscripts mean in these contexts? I think the $j$ refers to a column, but does $u^{i+1}$ mean raise that vector to that power? Do $u^{0}, v^{0}$ mean set everything to 1 in those vectors?

For the full algorithm:

[Algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzgK2.png)

In the full algorithm you also notice the variables $p $ and $q$, those are the column dimensions of two matrices(A, B, where shape(A) = (n x p), shape(B) = (n x q)) which were used to make up $K$

Comment: Presumably, these denote the iteration, hence why the initial values take superscript zero.

Comment: @Emily, I realized I should have given more information. Just to be sure, are your thoughts still the same given the new information?

Comment: Yes; notice step 5.

Comment: You can formally think of $u^i$ in this context as a function which takes input $i$ and outputs a vector in the vector space satisfying the iterative definition given in the algorithm.  They are presumably using superscript here in order to emphasize that they are not talking about the $i$'th *entry* of $u$ (sometimes written as $u_i$).